# Should I use a raw pointer here?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I'm building an application, and I am wondering if I should be using a raw pointer, smart pointer, or just the raw value.

Here it is:

```
class Test
{
public:
    void setSomething()
    {
        map = 
        {
            {},
            {} // Values
        }
// Concerned here because if I use a raw value than will C++ have to copy all values?
    }
    static Test& getInstance()
    {
        static Test test;
        return test;
    }
private:    
    std::unordered_map<..., ...> map;
};
```

Now I'm curious about `map`. The class `Test` is a singleton, and will only ever be initialized once.

After I call `setSomething`, I will just use `map` for getting a values from keys. Only when the application closes will `Test` finally be destroyed.

I'm kind of concerned because `map` can have millions of elements, and I do not want it to copy when I call `setSomething`. Does this mean I should use a raw pointer or smart pointer for `map`?

Comment: Raw pointer to what? The elements? The keys? Unordered maps are node-based, so resizing doesn't have to move or copy elements, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, I meant should I use a raw pointer to `map`

Comment: I see no need for a pointer to `map` here. Why do you think a pointer is needed? What is your actual concern? `setSomething()` has direct access to `map` and can freely modify its content without making a copy of it.

Comment: So assigning `map` to another large temporary will not copy?

Comment: If you're actually assigning to `map` itself, then all the data stored in it has to be freed and that will "always" require iterating over every "old" element, no matter where you put pointers etc (unless you want a memory leak). As for how data gets from the RHS to the LHS, that depends on whether you're moving (a `map` *is* just a pointer+some bookkeeping, and a move assignment is just repointing) or copying (this iterates over and copies each entry into new memory). This question is currently pretty unanswerable because you haven't shown what kind of assignment it is.

Comment: You haven't really told us what you're trying to _do_ with the map. What are the semantics? Where does the temporary come from, and what is your `Test` object supposed to contain _after_ a call to `setSomething()`?

Comment: I just edited it.

Comment: So you just want to reset map to discard all the millions of old entries, and instead contain millions of new entries? You can _move_ the temporaries to their new home, but you can't avoid destroying the old ones. Unless you can tell us something more about what these things are and where they come from.

Comment: I just edited it again.

Comment: And there are notionally millions of entries hardcoded in that expression `map = { ... }`? The details matter here. If that's a prvalue expression, it can be move assigned, and there is no copy. If that is a placeholder expression for something else, it may behave differently. You still haven't said if there are _already_ millions of _other_ values in map, so I don't know if you're worried about those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome new user.
There really isn't enough here to give good advice.

You're right that assigning a map could result in building a new map that is a copy of the right-hand side of the assignment and that could be onerous.

All the ideas you propose would work and it very much depends on your design which is best.

One possibility you haven't listed is a move assignment.
In C++ you can specify a value to be 'destructively assigned'.
So assigning `map= std::move(/** something **/)` wouldn't "make" a copy of the map but assign the internal representation of 'something' to map leaving `something` with a valid but unspecified (probably empty) value. Unless `something` is `const`...

In fact depending on what 'something' is may do that `automatically`.

Only use a `std::shared_ptr` if necessary. Only use `std::unique_ptr` if the object is taking 'ownership' of an object that is not a local or global variable.

Avoid using a 'raw' pointer in C++ unless an object, a reference, or one of the smart-pointer types won't do.

Go down that list and decide on the best implementation.
'Move assignment' is a fabulous feature of C++ and I only hesitate because it may not be the place to start! It's subtle.